# Randomly shuffle a sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, shuffle

is there an easy way to shuffle a sparse matrix in python?

This is how I shuffle a non-sparse matrix:

```
    index = np.arange(np.shape(matrix)[0])
    np.random.shuffle(index)
    return matrix[index]
```

How can I do it with numpy sparse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, found it. The sparse format looks a bit confusing in the print-out.

```
    index = np.arange(np.shape(matrix)[0])
    print index
    np.random.shuffle(index)
    return matrix[index, :]
```

Comment: Works only for csr_matrix. I am getting an error 'coo_matrix' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.

Comment: One should note that this creates a copy of the array, meaning that unless you have enough RAM to keep two copies in memory it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking to randomly get a subsample of rows from a sparse matrix, this related post may also be useful: [How should I go about subsampling from a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix and a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899681/how-should-i-go-about-subsampling-from-a-scipy-sparse-csr-csr-matrix-and-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

A better way can be shuffling the index of CSR Matrix and fetching the rows of matrix as such:

```
from random import shuffle
indices = np.arange(matrix.shape[0]) #gets the number of rows 
shuffle(indices)
shuffled_matrix = matrix[list(indices)]
```