# How should I go about subsampling from a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix and a list

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` that represents words in a document and a list of lists where each index represents the categories for each index in the matrix.

The problem that I am having is that I need to randomly select N amount of rows from the data.

So if my matrix looks like this

```
[1:3 2:3 4:4]
[1:5 2:5 5:4]
```

and my list of lists looked like this

```
((20,40) (80,50))
```

and I needed to sample 1 value I could end up with this

```
[1:3 2:3 4:4]
((20,40))
```

I have searched the scipy documentation but I cannot find a way to generate a new csr matrix using a list of indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply index a csr matrix by using a list of indices.  First we create a matrix, and look at it:

```
>>> m = csr_matrix([[0,0,1,0], [4,3,0,0], [3,0,0,8]])
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>>  print m.toarray()
[[0 0 1 0]
 [4 3 0 0]
 [3 0 0 8]]
```

Of course, we can easily just look a the first row:

```
>>> m[0]
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> print m[0].toarray()
[[0 0 1 0]]
```

But we can also look at the first and third row at once using the list `[0,2]` as an index:

```
>>> m[[0,2]]
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> print m[[0,2]].toarray()
[[0 0 1 0]
 [3 0 0 8]]
```

Now you can generate `N` random indices with no repeats (no replacement) using numpy's `choice`:

```
i = np.random.choice(np.arange(m.shape[0]), N, replace=False)
```

Then you can grab those indices from both your original matrix `m`:

```
sub_m = m[i]
```

To grab them from your categories list of lists, you must first make it an array, then you can index with the list `i`:

```
sub_c = np.asarray(categories)[i]
```

If you want to have a list of lists back, just use:

```
sub_c.tolist()
```

or, if what you really have/want is a tuple of tuples, I think you have to do it manually:

```
tuple(map(tuple, sub_c))
```

Comment: To make it more explicit that you are slicing rows, I guess you can use `m[0,:]` and `m[[0,2],:]` instead.

Comment: Yes, what @justhalf says is correct, `m[rows]` is equivalent to `m[rows,:]` and both keep all columns.