# How to efficiently shuffle a scipy sparse matrix, whatever its format?

Tags: numpy, matrix, random, scipy, shuffle

How can I shuffle the rows of a scipy sparse matrix?

There is a [scikitlearn.utils.shuffle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html), but it returns a new matrix, and so for a very large sparse matrix, the shuffling is not done in-place but instead the matrix is replicated.

There is [numpy.random.Generator.shuffle](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html#numpy.random.Generator.shuffle), but it seems to [work only for CSR matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230717/1719931).

How to efficiently shuffle the rows of a scipy sparse matrix, whatever the format used to store it in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm consolidating my comments into one answer. It's not a solution, but editing is easier.

If you hope to find an efficient row shuffle regardless of sparse format, you have not studied the sparse matrix documentation enough. Only `csr` and `lil` store their data in row-oriented fashion.

I can imagine doing an in-place row shuffle with the `lil` format. While `csr` stores data in a row oriented manner, row shuffle will be more complicated, and difficult to do in-place.

Tracing through the `scikit` shuffle, I see it just comes down to `matrix[index,:]` (where `index` is a sampling without replacement). That's the same as in the CSR link. For what it's worth, CSR indexing actually uses matrix-multiplication, using a specially constructed 'extractor' matrix.

Shuffling lists is relatively efficient, in-place or not, since it just involves creating a new list of pointers/references to the row lists. Row shuffle of a dense numpy array requires copying all the data.  It can be done in compiled code, but it still requires enough buffer space for a whole copy.